# Android OkHttpClient Retrofit and caching questions

Tags: android, caching, retrofit, okhttp

Analyzing some previously written code I have some questions concerning the set up with OkHttpClient. We did create a single OkHttpClient instance and reuse it for all of our HTTP calls. We execute REST API calls and caching is not needed.
However I do see some code in an interceptor

`request = request.newBuilder().header("Cache-Control", "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=${120}").build()`

**Question 1:** Would this have any effect if caching is not enabled?

Secondly there is one API call that fetches configuration data and I feel it can benefit from caching.

**Question 2:** Can we enable caching for just one call, say, if we customize the client using *newBuilder()*?

Answer (score 0):

1. It could have an effect on caches between yourself and the remote service. But this specific interceptor seems designed to force the request to only use the local cache, and not attempt to use the network.

https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-cache-control/only-if-cached/

> > To rephrase my question slightly ...if no cache is set on the original call then the request with the cache-control will not do anything right?

2. Typically you would not need an interceptor, instead you would apply the cache settings to the request.

https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-cache/

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .cacheControl(new CacheControl.Builder().noCache().build())
    .url("http://publicobject.com/helloworld.txt")
    .build();
```

> > Not sure this addresses the second question. I'm asking if we have set up one single OkHttpClient instance can we have only some requests cached or the fact that we turn on cache for one request turns it on for all other requests onward?